# How can I get data from input without a form in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm writing a web scraper on Python Scrapy, which should get data of input from [this](https://www.guidestar.org/search) website.

When I choose a state on the left side of the site, it sends a `POST` request.
The `POST` request (chosen state: "Alaska"):

```json
{
    "CurrentPage": "1",
    "SearchType": "org",
    "GroupExemption": "",
    "AffiliateOrgName": "",
    "RelatedOrgName": "",
    "RelatedOrgEin": "",
    "RelationType": "",
    "RelatedOrgs": "",
    "SelectedCityNav[]": "",
    "SelectedCountyNav[]": "",
    "Eins": "",
    "ul": "",
    "PCSSubjectCodes[]": "",
    "PeoplePCSSubjectCodes[]": "",
    "PCSPopulationCodes[]": "",
    "AutoSelectTaxonomyFacet": "",
    "AutoSelectTaxonomyText": "",
    "Keywords": "",
    "State": "Alaska",
    "City": "",
    "PeopleZip": "",
    "PeopleZipRadius": "Zip+Only",
    "PeopleCity": "",
    "PeopleRevenueRangeLow": "$0",
    "PeopleRevenueRangeHigh": "max",
    "PeopleAssetsRangeLow": "$0",
    "PeopleAssetsRangeHigh": "max",
    "Sort": ""
}
```

The thing is there is no form, just input, and I don't know how to deal with that. I'm using `scrapy.http.Request` to send a `POST` request. And when I crawl my spider, it gives me the html of the website with no states chosen.
My spider:

```py
import urllib
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class NonprofitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nonprofit'

    def parse(self, response):

        url = 'https://www.guidestar.org/search' # or maybe 'https://www.guidestar.org/search/SubmitSearch'?

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        }

        data = {
            "CurrentPage": "1",
            "SearchType": "org",
            "GroupExemption": "",
            "AffiliateOrgName": "",
            "RelatedOrgName": "",
            "RelatedOrgEin": "",
            "RelationType": "",
            "RelatedOrgs": "",
            "SelectedCityNav[]": "",
            "SelectedCountyNav[]": "",
            "Eins": "",
            "ul": "",
            "PCSSubjectCodes[]": "",
            "PeoplePCSSubjectCodes[]": "",
            "PCSPopulationCodes[]": "",
            "AutoSelectTaxonomyFacet": "",
            "AutoSelectTaxonomyText": "",
            "Keywords": "",
            "State": "Alaska",
            "City": "",
            "PeopleZip": "",
            "PeopleZipRadius": "Zip+Only",
            "PeopleCity": "",
            "PeopleRevenueRangeLow": "$0",
            "PeopleRevenueRangeHigh": "max",
            "PeopleAssetsRangeLow": "$0",
            "PeopleAssetsRangeHigh": "max",
            "Sort": ""
        }

        return Request(
            url=url,
            method='POST',
            headers=headers,
            body=urllib.parse.urlencode(data),
            callback=self.start
        )

    def start(self, response):

        print('response', response)

        open_in_browser(response)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the page in your browsers inspector? There is a form that wraps most of the page content that points to a "/search/SubmitSearch" action with the method "GET".

Comment: I mislooked it, my bad. But if the form is with the method "GET", why when I choose a state it sends a POST request to "/search/SubmitSearch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you recreate the request you can parse the data from the json file

```
import urllib
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class NonprofitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nonprofit'
    start_urls = ['https://www.guidestar.org/search']

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.guidestar.org/search/SubmitSearch'

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        }

        data = {
            "CurrentPage": "1",
            "SearchType": "org",
            "GroupExemption": "",
            "AffiliateOrgName": "",
            "RelatedOrgName": "",
            "RelatedOrgEin": "",
            "RelationType": "",
            "RelatedOrgs": "",
            "SelectedCityNav[]": "",
            "SelectedCountyNav[]": "",
            "Eins": "",
            "ul": "",
            "PCSSubjectCodes[]": "",
            "PeoplePCSSubjectCodes[]": "",
            "PCSPopulationCodes[]": "",
            "AutoSelectTaxonomyFacet": "",
            "AutoSelectTaxonomyText": "",
            "Keywords": "",
            "State": "Alaska",
            "City": "",
            "PeopleZip": "",
            "PeopleZipRadius": "Zip+Only",
            "PeopleCity": "",
            "PeopleRevenueRangeLow": "$0",
            "PeopleRevenueRangeHigh": "max",
            "PeopleAssetsRangeLow": "$0",
            "PeopleAssetsRangeHigh": "max",
            "Sort": ""
        }

        return Request(
            url=url,
            method='POST',
            headers=headers,
            body=urllib.parse.urlencode(data),
            callback=self.start
        )

    def start(self, response):
        print('response', response)
        json_data = response.json()
        for element in json_data['Hits']:
            OrgName = element['OrgName']
            Ein = element['Ein']
            # ...
            # ...
            # ...
            # ...
            # and so on
```